# Model Driven Architecture Approach in programming / modelling

Tags: architecture, modeling, model

I know the basics of the model driven architecture: it is all about model the system which I want to create and create the core code afterwards. I used CORBA a while ago. First thing that I needed to do was to create an abstract interface (some kind of model of the system I want to build) and generate core code later.

But I have a different question: is model driven architecture a broad approach or not? I mean, let's say, that I have the language (modelling language) in which I want to model EXISTING system (opposite to the system I want to CREATE), and then analyze the model of the created system and different facts about that modeled abstraction.

In this case, can the process I described above be considered the model driven architecture approach? I mean, I have the model, but this is the model of the existing system, not the system to be created.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article on MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture)?  Among other things, it states that *"The model-driven architecture approach defines system functionality using a platform-independent model (PIM) using an appropriate domain-specific language (DSL).

Then, given a platform model corresponding to CORBA, .NET, the Web, etc., the PIM is translated to one or more platform-specific models (PSMs) that computers can run."*

Answer (score 1):

I donot think that your model-driven-analysing approach is helpful until you want to remplement the old system.

The benefit about model-driven-design is that you create a model and the basic code is generated from it if you have the apropriate codegenerators.

For example the [hybris-shop-system](http://www.hybris.com) is implemented this way:

you create a modell (an xml-file) and database-schema, java-database-access-code and gui for shop-maintenance is generated from that model.

example:

If you add a new attribute "lastOrderDate" to the model-file, you get the generated java/gui code from it.

you can reverse-engeneer a model from your existing database-modell but it is quite likely that the corresponding generated code for businessmodell/databaseaccess/gui will not compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

My own limited experiences of attempting to use modeling on existing code have not been very satisfying. I pointed one "reverse engineering" tool at a fairly trivial Android program written in Java and the result was an incomprehensible mess of UML class boxes and relationships.

My guess is that MDA might be helpful if you were assigned to rework some legacy code...say taking some sort of monolithic UNIX app and restructuring it so that some portions ran in the cloud, some on iOS, and some on Android. You could model the pieces (at a fairly high level!) model the interactions between the pieces, and create wrappers for chunks of legacy code that you would put inside some of the wrappers..(?) Other pieces (iOS for example) might need to be totally re-implemented.

However, whether this approach would actually work well in practice or not would depend heavily on the specifics of the task at hand.